# Query an elastic search index having colon/hyphen in index name

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have an elastic search index "auction:msdn" on which I need to run a query. I keep getting "index_not_found_exception" when I try to access the index.
Can someone help me on how to access/query indices with colons/hyphens present in the index-name.
This is the code snippet I'm using to query

```
client.search({index:"auction:msdn",body:{query:{"match_all":{}}}},(err,response)=>{
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else {
       console.log(response)
   }
})
```

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch you are using?

Comment: @Ikatiforis v6.8.18

Comment: Use the cat indices API to list all available indices: `GET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices'`

Comment: I'm able to see all the indices present, but how do i query the index through code?

Comment: Which version of elastic node client are you using? It seems like going forward ie in ES 7.0 `:` is not allowed.